# Add event listener to Grafana Table Panel plugin

Tags: javascript, grafana

I am trying to add event listener to Table Panel, to be able to click on specific cell and taking unique ID go to detail page, which gonna give information about selected item.
To accomplish that I went to specific folder which contain Table Panel :

```
/usr/share/grafana/public/app/plugins/panel/table
```

there I selected rendered.js file, opened it and tried to add my code:

```
this.table.rows[f].on('click', function onClick() {
        //function code
        });
```

above

```
for (var g = this.table.rows[f], h = "", i = "", j = 0; j < this.table.columns.length; j++) h += this.renderCell(j, g[j], f === c);
```

string but cannot do make it work.

Can somebody propose any solution to add event listener to Grafana Table Panel plugin?

Comment: Do you get an error? If yes pls post it.

Comment: It wasn't error. Just nothing happened when I added this.table.rows[f].on('click', function onClick() {
        //function code
});

Comment: It wasn't error. Just nothing happened when I added this.table.rows[f].on('click', function onClick() {
        //function code
});  
that part of code but event still doesn't appears so I post the question how to add event listener to grafana Table Panel plugin correctly

Comment: I guess you need to get the grafana src. Make your changes there and build it.